# How does gsutil rsync determine whether a file is old or new when syncing two folders?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm rsyncing files to a DRA bucket, and I need to make sure that when a file is newer in the source folder it must be synced to the destination folder.

Right now I am using MD5 checksum to be 100% sure, but this is too slow on a data set of 8TB with a very large amount of files.

If I disable the MD5 checking, how does gsutil rsync determine whether a file should get synced or not?

Comment: To improve checksum speed you should use a compiled CRC32c. check with 'gsutil ver -l ' if you are using a compiled CRC32c. For information on getting a compiled CRC32C implementation, see 'gsutil help crc32c'.

Comment: If you have a large number of objects to synchronize you might want to use the gsutil -m option, to perform parallel (multi-threaded/multi-processing)
  synchronization that will provide a large performance boost if either the
  source or destination (or both) is a cloud URL. If both source and
  destination are file URLs the -m option will typically thrash the disk and
  slow synchronization down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From gsutil rsync --help:

CHANGE DETECTION ALGORITHM
  To determine if a file or object has changed gsutil rsync first checks whether
  the source and destination sizes match. If they match, it next checks if their
  checksums match, using checksums if available (see below).

Unlike the Unix
  rsync command, gsutil rsync does not use timestamps to determine if the
  file/object changed, because the GCS API does not permit the caller to set an
  object's timestamp (hence, timestamps of identical files/objects cannot be
  made to match).

Checksums will not be available in two cases:

1. When synchronizing to or from a file system. By default, gsutil does not
    checksum files, because of the slowdown caused when working with large
    files. You can cause gsutil to checksum files by using the gsutil rsync -c
    option, at the cost of increased local disk I/O and run time when working
    with large files. You should consider using the -c option if your files can
    change without changing sizes (e.g., if you have files that contain fixed
    width data, such as timestamps).
2. When comparing composite GCS objects with objects at a cloud provider that
    does not support CRC32C (which is the only checksum available for composite
    objects). See 'gsutil help compose' for details about composite objects.

Regards,
Paolo